# How to configure timeout for maven-changes-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-changes-plugin

I have a [maven-changes-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/) configured for a build process. Sometimes, JIRA intranet server is down and the build takes ages waiting for a long timeout on JIRA.

Is there a way to configure the timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear so.  The source for the [RestJiraDownloader](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/jira/RestJiraDownloader.html), the class that queries JIRA for issues, has hard-coded timeout values.  Lines [562-566](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/jira/RestJiraDownloader.html#L562) indicate a connection timeout of 36 seconds and a receive timeout of 32 seconds.

Comment: An improvement request has been submitted: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCHANGES-341